# How to print a result and other words inside a print function in python?

Tags: python

I am a new learner in python and a beginner in programming. Please forgive me if my question is below low level. I used to print the result and other sentences beside the result in C programming, but I cannot do the same in python. My error screenshot is provided with the question:

[image]

Comment: Please share the code and error message as text, not as a screenshot

Comment: @Mureinik thanks for the information, as I am a beginner in programming also I am beginner in stackoverflow!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You cannot concat a string and a float value. You need to cast in string or use f-strings in python3.

```
weight_kg = input('Enter your weight(in kgms): ')
weight_lbs = int(weight_kg) * 2.20462
print('Weight in pounds is' + str(weight_lbs)) # cast to str
print(f'Weight in pounds is {weight_lbs}') # f-strings format in python3
```

Comment: Thanks for both the solutions.

Answer (score 0):

Only String can be added to string. That's what python interpreter is complaining about.

Old ways:

```
print("Weight in pound is: %d" %weight_lbs)

print("Weight in pound is: {}".format(%weight_lbs))
```

You can use f-string instead:

```
print(f"Weight in pound is: {weight_lbs}")
```

Read section 7.1.1 in [python docs](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/inputoutput.html#formatted-string-literals) for more detail about f-string (formatted strings).

Comment: Just FYI - In your first solution, the format specifier should be `%f` not `%d`, otherwise it will print only integer value and discard decimal numbers.

Comment: Didn't know that variable was float, thanks.

Answer (score 0):

The easiest and most modern way to do what you want is to use f-strings.

E.g., `print(f'Weight in pounds is {weight_lbs}.')`

See https://docs.python.org/3/reference/lexical_analysis.html#f-strings for detailed information.

Answer (score 0):

Another solution would be to use a placeholder similar to those in C.
The Code would look like this:

```
print("Weight in pound is: {}".format(weight_lbs))
```

The `{}` is indicating that you want to input text in this position.
The `.format(...)` is "automatically transforming" your desired input into a string.